# Point of Service (Receipt Printer)

Tags: point-of-sale, opos

I am trying to find the best method of developing a piece of software for a Point of Sale Device (Receipt Printer). I want to develop this using a Microsoft Language and have been able to find Microsoft POS and I think OPOS that would work for this, however the devices I have been able to find are like £200.

Is there a company that sell cheap pos/opos receipt printers, or a method of doing this such as an SDK with a device or anything.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished developing some C#.Net code to communicate with an Epson TM-T88V Parallel/USB Printer. They are very affordable and good printers for POS use. I just saw one on eBay for about $200 US. This printer has both USB and Parallel connection options. Epson provides the OPOS Service Objects as a download from thier website. Once you install the Service Objects (a seperate installation msi) you can use the POS for .Net SDK to write software to control the printer.

I do not recommend attempting to create a Service Object or OPOS driver for a printer that does not have one. It is worth your time to just send an email to the manufactor before buying a printer to ask for these drivers. In my experience so far all manufactuers have comeup with them despite not having them available on thier website.